# Calculating coordinates when only bearing of two points and distance between them is known?

Tags: coordinates, gis-principle

I have bearing of two points 115 33' 09" and distance between these two points is 1464.36m. Is it possible to get the unknown coordinates from this data?

Comment: If you have coordinates of one of the points - yes.

Comment: Its unfortunate that i don't have one of the points

Comment: No, not without one of the points. Based on the length and bearing, we could probably identify a latitude, but the longitude could be anything.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can. One could use the [Great Circle method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) of calculating distances between two points on the Earth.

An example of such calculator is available [here](http://www.fcc.gov/encyclopedia/find-terminal-coordinates-given-bearing-and-distance).

Comment: Do i need one of the coordinates on this one??

Comment: Of course you do. You ask "If I walk one kilometer to the north, where do I come?". It really depends on where you stand right now. However, if you also know how much 1464.36 meters is in degrees it may be solvable because the length of one degree varies according to where you are on the earth.

Comment: @user30184 for the latitude you are right, but 1 degree eastwards the ratio is still the same. Or 10, or 100.

Comment: @AndreJ Let's wait till some geodesy folks join discussion. Because earth is not sphere but flattened I do not believe it is exactly so. But didn't you think in a wrong way about eastwards/northwards? Myself I tend to imagine that the slices of the earth orange get narrower near the poles in east-west direction.

Comment: @user30184 Half true: On 60° latidude, from 9°East to 10° East should be as long as from 11° to 12° East. Otherwise it would not be an ellipsoid (rather a potatoe), and rotating rather asynchronous.

Comment: You have the symmetry problem for either latitude or longitude. On an ellipsoid a degree of latitude has a different length depending on where it is, but that doesn't tell you what longitude you're at.

Comment: The link in your answer appears broken

Comment: As many folks had rightly pointed out (in the comments) - either one of the (two) coordinates must be known, then only the bearing and distance can be used to compute the other coordinate. "Coordinate" means XY (or XYZ) - hence longitude without latitude or vice-versa does not give enough input.